# A valid React element (or null) must be returned, error in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a component to `authenticate` links in my app.

I want to use it like:

```
<Authenticated>
    <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
</Authenticated>
```

For that I have written this code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Authenticated extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let content = null;
    if(this.props.authenticate) {
      content = this.props.children
    }
    return (
      <span>{content}</span>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    authenticate: state.auth.authenticated
  }

}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Authenticated)
```

Its showing me link properly after validation. But the problem here is `span`.

`<span>{content}</span>`, Its returning `Link` wrapped with `span`. Which is not allowing me to make it global (place it any where).

If I will remove `span` wrapper its throwing error.

> Uncaught Error: Authenticated.render(): A valid React element (or
>   null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or
>   some other invalid object.
>       at invariant (invariant.js:44)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:831)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:362)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:258)
>       at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:46)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:371)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:258)
>       at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:46)
>       at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:238)
>       at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:691)

Please help me out to remove `span` from output.

Comment: try to use div instead of span.

Comment: Both has same impact. It will block the css written for the inner component.

Comment: JSX requires a group of elements to be wrapped in a containing element. So if you want to display multiple children, they will need to be wrapped in a containing span/div or other

Comment: what do you mean by placing it anywhere?

Comment: @TMitchell ya thats true. So is there any way to avoid that to impact the css causing on the child components.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra, Ran across this same issue couple of days earliers, but i reckon the best we can do is structure our CSS in a way that doesnt break.

Comment: Its hard to do as we have multiple projects sharing same css.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), as per DOC:

> Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes
>   to the DOM.

Write it like this:

```
class Authenticated extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let content = null;
    if(this.props.authenticate) {
      content = this.props.children
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragmen>{content}</React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

In actual dom, react will skip the fragment and render the content directly.

Comment: I don't want to pass it like that. It should be child component. Possibly there could be multiple links inside it. Like: `login`, `register` or other components are also possible. So this solution will not work in my case.

Comment: just check once whether its working or not ?? to figure out where is the problem.

Comment: Even my code is working with div and span. So its for sure will work. Problem here is how to avoid `div` or `span` or there impact on child components.

Answer (score 1):

What if you would wrap your `content` not in a `span` but in an empty element?

```
<>{content}</>
```

The other can be shorter too.

```
{this.props.authenticate ? (<>{this.props.children}</> : null}
```